# How to access property of a class whose name is in a variable

Tags: c#

I have a class with is a collection of XPaths. I want to pass the name of the field and want to get the XPath for that field. The problem here is I have to store the passed value in a variable and putting an if condition to check for the corresponding XPath variable as shown below.

As of now, I am using the if condition and I can use switch condition as well but this solution is not feasible as the collection of XPath will grow and it will become unmanageable.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new Program().IReturnXpath("LastName"));
        }

        public string IReturnXpath(String nameOfField)
        {
            if (nameOfField.Equals("Lastname"))
                return new XpathCollection().Lastname;
            else if (nameOfField.Equals("Firstname"))
                return new XpathCollection().Firstname;
            else
                return "Xpath not found";
        }

        class XpathCollection
        {
            public string Lastname = "xpath for lastname";
            public string Firstname = "xpath for firstname";
        }
    }
```

Comment: [How to get a property value based on the name](//stackoverflow.com/q/5508050)

Comment: For your current example, it will be better to use `Dictionary<string, string>` instead (or `Dictionary<string, XPath>` if they are `XPath`s).

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain how Microsoft solved exact same problem.

`System.Drawing.Color` has many properties each reflecting a single color. `Color` also has a `FromName` method which allows you to find a color by string parameter. Almost exactly your problem.

As you can see in their, implementation, they create a `Hashtable` and by using reflection they fill it. Next time someone asks for a color they just lookup and return it. Put generation code in a static constructor and you are done.

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/ColorConverter.cs,d06a69beb42834b2